# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in openpyxl python

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, openpyxl

I am creating Invoice generator using Tkinter python but I am getting permission error
All the respective files were closed during program execution. In Tkinter window, once I click add button it shows the error which is mentioned below

My program

```
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import date

# from win32com import client
wb = load_workbook('E://invoice.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']


#Date 
sheet.cell(row=7,column=6).value = date.today()
#BILL NUMBER 
temp = sheet.cell(row=8,column=6).value
temp = int(temp[1:])
new_no = temp+1
sheet.cell(row=8,column=6).value = 'B0'+str(new_no)

#Making Sheet values blank
sheet.cell(row=8,column=1).value = ""
for i in range(17,27):
    sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value = None
    sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value = None
    sheet.cell(row=i,column=4).value = None
co=16     
def get1():
    global co
    co+=1
    print("get")
    global ent1
    global ent2
    global ent3
    global ent4
    client_name = ent1.get()
    item = ent2.get()
    price = ent3.get()
    quantity = ent4.get()
    sheet.cell(row=8,column=1).value = client_name
    sheet.cell(row=co,column=1).value = item
    sheet.cell(row=co,column=3).value = price
    sheet.cell(row=co,column=4).value = quantity
    print(client_name,item,price,quantity)
    wb.save('E://invoice.xlsx')

def pdf():
    global wb
    wb.close()
    from win32com import client
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    wb = load_workbook('E://invoice.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    #sheet name
    bill_no = sheet.cell(row=8,column=6).value
    cus_name = sheet.cell(row=8,column=1).value

    input_file = r'E:invoice.xlsx'
    output_file = r'E:exel//'+(bill_no+'_'+cus_name)+'.pdf'
    app = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    app.Interactive = False
    app.Visible = False
    Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(input_file)
    try:
        Workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to convert in PDF format.Please confirm environment meets all the requirements  and try again")
        print(str(e))
    finally:
        Workbook.Close()
#     app.Exit()

    
    
window = Tk(screenName = "vcs",baseName = "ver 1.0")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.title("Vaibhav Computer Services")
widget = Label(window, text = "Vaibhav Computer Services",fg='blue',font=("bold",16))
widget.pack()


lab1 = Label(window, text = "Client Name :",fg='blue',font=("bold",16)).place(x=90,y=60)
ent1 = Entry(window)
ent1.place(x=230,y=65)

lab2 = Label(window, text = "Item  :",fg='blue',font=("bold",16)).place(x=90,y=100)
ent2 = Entry(window)
ent2.place(x=230,y=105)
print(ent2)

lab3 = Label(window, text = "Price  :",fg='blue',font=("bold",16)).place(x=90,y=140)
ent3 = Entry(window)
ent3.place(x=230,y=145)
# ent3.bind('<KeyPress>',keybind1)
print(ent3)

lab4 = Label(window, text = "Quantity  :",fg='blue',font=("bold",16)).place(x=90,y=180)
ent4 = Entry(window)
ent4.place(x=230,y=185)
print(ent4)

#Button
button1 = Button(window,text="Add",font=("bold"),command=get1).place(x=250,y=230)

button2 = Button(window,text="Generate PDF",font=("bold"),command=pdf).place(x=200,y=290)
window.mainloop()
wb.save('E://invoice.xlsx')
```

All the respective files was closed during program execution

Error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pranu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-22-6691247dc7ef>", line 44, in get1
    wb.save('E://invoice.xlsx')
  File "c:\users\pranu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "c:\users\pranu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "c:\users\pranu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E://invoice.xlsx'
```

Comment: Hello, Don't need to post the entire code when you need to solve a problem, just post the relevant part.

Comment: I don't read your code, but did you read the error message? it seems to be obvious you can't write in the place you asked because you're not allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

In my computer this error will appear when the file is open and we use `wb.save("E://invoice.xlsx")`.
also see this code.

```
from os import startfile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# now file will start
startfile("Test.xlsx")

workbook = load_workbook("Test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

# sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1, value = "Hello")
sheet["A1"] = "Hello"

workbook.save("Test.xlsx")
```

and the output is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Test.py", line 10, in <module>
    workbook.save("a.xlsx")
  File "C:\Python\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 409, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 292, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python 3.8\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Test.xlsx'
```

but if we use

```
from os import startfile
from openpyxl import load_workbook    

workbook = load_workbook("Test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

# sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1, value = "Hello")
sheet["A1"] = "Hello"

workbook.save("Test.xlsx")

# now file will start
startfile("Test.xlsx")
```

which the file start in the end we have no error.
In the first one file was running and then we see that error
but in the second the file was not running and we used `startfile("Test.xlsx")` after the `workbook.save("Test.xlsx")`.

also send "invoice.xlsx" to "benyamin.zavieh.ba@gmail.com" i want to test some code that if it work i will send it to you :)

(I have some ideas about your code i'm glad it will work)

Comment: Please also explain how to fix it / why does it happens. This answer does not show effort.